# Remove duplicate values from NSArray while appending

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray, duplicates

I have 2 arrays, one of which is `NSMutableArray` (say mutArrayA) and other is `NSArray(arrayB)`.
I am appending `arrayB` to `mutArrayA` and at the same time I want to remove duplicates if any i.e. I don't want any duplicates in mutArrayA.

One way I know to do this is iterating over each object in the arrayB and checking its index using `indexOfObject` which if found in mutArrayA, then don't append that object to mutArrayA else append it. However I was trying to look for some quicker way to do this and I came across the following solution on this site which goes as below:

```
[mutArrayA setArray:[[NSSet setWithArray:arrayB] allObjects]];
```

When I execute this, my mutArrayA gets replaced with objects in arrayB because of setArray. Is there a quicker way using which I can append the array without getting the duplicates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[mutArrayA addObjectsFromArray:[[NSSet setWithArray:arrayB] allObjects]];
[mutArrayA setArray:[[NSSet setWithArray:mutArrayA] allObjects]];
```

So initially you remove duplicates from arrayB, append it, and then apply the same principle to remove duplicates from `mutArrayA` if there are any after appending

UPDATE

You need to override `isEqual:` method for your class. I'll give you an example by assuming your objects contain `NSString` objects.

```
- (BOOL)isEqual:(MyClass *)object
{
  return [self.key isEqualToString:object.key] && [self.value isEqualToString:object.value];
}
```

You need also to override `hash` method like this:

```
- (NSUInteger)hash {
return [self.key hash] ^ [self.value hash];
}
```

The problem is `NSSet` doesn't remove duplicates cause it thinks they're are not duplicates so by overriding this method you give it a clue of how to compare your objects for equality

Comment: This didn't work for me. Its giving me duplicates in mutArrayA after I run the code.

Comment: So any idea how does the NSSet check for the duplicate? Does it check the contents of the object or its pointer value?

Comment: i suppose it checks their hash value

Comment: Hmmm then that could be reason its not working for me.

Comment: There is a key distinction you should make here.  When you say duplicates do you mean in an isEqual sense, or has equal values? You may need to override your isEqual method to get the behavior you're going after. Have a look at this code.

Comment: By duplicate values I mean to have equal value. The objects inside both the arrays are like this <myClass 0x16c38af0> {
  key = Testing 123;
  value = Testing the app
},

Comment: @Andrey - Hmmm its strange why non of the solutions are working for me. I wonder if its the key value pair thing inside the object thats creating the issue or else I need to handle it in a different way maybe.

Comment: @tech_learning did you try overriding isEqual: for myClass? that's the case

Comment: @tech_learning you need also to override hash method. see the update. i finally made it work. only overriding isequal is not enough

Comment: @AndreyChernukha - Overriding isEqual and hash methods helped it to work. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: One quick question, I understand reason for overriding isEqual method, but why exactly do we need to override hash?

Comment: i think that the answer to my own question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15985784/cocoa-object-equality-and-hashing-clarification may help you understand it

Answer (score 1):

Implement the following method and invoke it using your array to be traversed.

```
- (NSMutableArray *)removeDuplicates:(NSMutableArray *)array{
    NSArray *copy = [array copy];
    NSInteger index = [copy count] - 1;
    for (id object in [copy reverseObjectEnumerator]) {
        if ([array indexOfObject:object inRange:NSMakeRange(0, index)] != NSNotFound) {
            [array removeObjectAtIndex:index];
        }
        index--;
    }
    [copy release];
    copy = nil;
    return array;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
[mutArrayA addObjectsFromArray: arrayB];
[mutArrayA setArray:[[NSSet setWithArray:mutArrayA] allObjects]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Put both arrays into a set which will remove duplicates, but will not guarantee order. If order is important then another solution will need to be used.

```
NSMutableSet *set = [[NSMutableSet alloc] init];
[set addObjectsFromArray:mutArrayA];
[set addObjectsFromArray:arrayB];

mutArrayA = [[set allObjects] mutableCopy];
```

Comment: By order do you mean sort order? I am sorting mutArrayA after appending, so that shouldn't be an issue I guess

Comment: However I will give your solution a try to understand how it works.

Comment: An NSSet/NSMutableSet will hold an unordered collection of distinct objects. So the objects won't be located at a distinct index and won't come out of the set in the same order every time. Sorting the array after retrieving it from the set will work fine.

Comment: Nopes this solution also didn't help me. I wonder if its the format of the data thats creating the issue or maybe [set allObjects] could be checking the pointer value of the objects. The data I have inside both the arrays is of this format: <myClass 0x16c38af0> {
  key = Testing 123;
  value = Testing the app
},

Answer (score 0):

There is a key distinction you should make here.  When you say duplicates do you mean in an isEqual sense, or has equal values? You may need to override your isEqual method to get the behavior you're going after. If you are using custom objects, by default your custom objects are only equal if they have the same pointer reference.  ie.

```
[[[MyCustomObject alloc]init]isEqual:[[MyCustomObject alloc]init]] == No;

Whereas 

[[[NSString alloc] init] isEqual:[[NSString alloc] init]] == YES;
```

Assuming you are correctly handling isEqual (or implementing your own method to determine equality) you could convert your array to an NSSet and then back as previously suggested.

```
NSSet *compositeSet = [NSSet setWithArray:[mutArrayA addObjectsFromArray:mutArrayB]];
NSArray *deduplicatedArray = [compositeSet allObjects];
```

Answer (score 0):

The KVC Object Operator @distinctUnionOfObjects might be helpful here.

```
[mutArrayA addObjectsFromArray:arrayB];
uniquearray = [mutArrayA valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects.self"];
```

Here's an [NSArray category](https://github.com/pm-dev/PMUtils/blob/master/Pod/Classes/Foundation%2BPMUtils/NSArray%2BPMUtils.m#L65-70) for getting a distinct array.

Answer (score 0):

This might not apply to the original poster's question, but this page was the first search result for the terms I used, so I'm posting my solution here in case it helps someone else.

I wanted to merge two arrays of `NSStrings` (which were both being used as keys in `NSDictionaries`), but I needed to keep the sort order of the first array. So I wanted an array that was made up of the sorted array, plus any unique values in the second array. I used the following code:

```
NSArray *sortedArray = @[@"Aardvark", @"Bandicoot", @"Catbird", @"Dingo", @"Elephant shrew", @"Flagellate"];
NSArray *array2 = @[@"Zebra", @"Aardvark", @"Yak", @"Dingo", @"Xeromys"];

NSMutableArray *nonDupes = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:array2];
[nonDupes removeObjectsInArray:sortedArray];
NSArray *combinedArray = [sortedArray arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:nonDupes];

NSLog(@"combinedArray: %@", combinedArray);
```

Output:

```
2017-05-01 14:46:39.860 App [23038:6945531] combinedArray: (
    Aardvark,
    Bandicoot,
    Catbird,
    Dingo,
    "Elephant shrew",
    Flagellate,
    Zebra,
    Yak,
    Xeromys
)
```